# Does anybody remember the Star Wars Marvel comics between Star Wars and Empire Strikes Back?

Tags: star-wars

As far as I remember, it went on for 5-6 issues and was mostly taking place on a Waterworld-type all-water planet.  Blasters, skimmers, wooden ships.

The funny, and somewhat creepy in hindsight bit, is that Luke and Leia were a couple.  Not entirely unexpected, there had been a bit of romantic vibes in the air between those 2 in the first movie.  Which Empire, of course, quickly switched over to Leia and Han.

How did that romance see the light of day, considering their later-to-be-revealed sibling relationship?  Seems like not exercising enough control on your spinoff agreements and plot arcs.

Comment: You've got several questions here (and a rather irrelevant point in brackets), I suggest you focus on one specific question, as opposed to three separate questions. But yes, I do remember the comics.

Comment: The Drexel waterworld arc spans [issues 11 to 15](http://coldbananas.com/2013/06/comic-books/star-wars-flashback-marvel-comics-11-17-1978/) of [the 107-issue series](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_(Marvel)).

Comment: @Edlothiad  Fair enough, changed a bit, but feel free to edit.  Bottom line:  seems like a massive goof, only saved by the obscurity of the material in question and the fact that it was far enough removed from Lucas' direct control that it could disowned if need be.  How did it come to pass?

Comment: @Gaultheria Thanks for reminding me of that.  I recall buying one or two Star Wars comic in 1978, and all I remember of them is that there was a crashed Star Destroyer floating on  water planet.

Comment: @Gaultheria  You know, I think it was the series that I had been looking at.  The covers in the link are very familiar and the chronology works better than a 95-96 publication date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are almost undoubtedly thinking of the comic adaptation of [*Splinter of the Mind's Eye*](http://marvel.com/comics/series/20221/star_wars_splinter_of_the_minds_eye_1995_-_1996), based on [the novel of the same name](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Splinter_of_the_Mind%27s_Eye) and included four issues published by Dark Horse and later Marvel Comics.

I haven't read it in years, and don't recall wooden ships specifically, but there was a swamp/water world, and Luke/Leia had more of a romantic relationship. It took place between *A New Hope* and *The Empire Strikes Back.*

The original book was published in 1978, and the comic adaptation was released between 1995 and 1996.

*Splinter of the Mind's Eye* was an interesting production, as it was originally written as a [back-up sequel to *Star Wars*](http://legendsrevealed.com/entertainment/2016/05/05/was-splinters-of-the-minds-eye-originally-written-as-a-cheap-film-sequel-to-star-wars/). In the event that Star Wars was not financially successful enough for Fox to pick up the sequel, Lucas wanted a sequel that he could finance and produce himself on the cheap. This led to Alan Dean Foster being hired to write a sequel separately with little input from Lucas himself.

In an interview with [Yahoo](https://www.yahoo.com/entertainment/star-wars-splinter-of-the-minds-eye-alan-dean-113794483282.html), Alan Dean Foster explained the situation:

> My contract was originally for two books: the novelization of the first film and then a sequel book, because George — being a student of Disney, I’m sure — wanted more material in case the movie was a success. He wanted something out there that the hoped-for fans would be able to enjoy while he was busy making the second film. The only restriction placed on me was that the follow-up novel had to be filmable on a low budget. That’s why I set it on a fog-shrouded planet. A lot of the action takes place in the fog or underground, which facilitates shooting with cheap backgrounds. The book originally opened with a fairly complex space battle that forces Luke and Leia down on this planet, and George had me cut that out because it would have been expensive to film.

Wookieepedia describes the end of the novel:

> The two Yuzzem, Hin and Kee, never return. Luke wonders why, but then is crushed by rubble that fell from the cracking, ancient ceiling. Darth Vader then enters the Temple of Pomojema after having turned off the droids and killed Captain-Supervisor Grammel, Kee, and supposedly Hin. Leia takes up Luke's lightsaber and begins fighting Darth Vader, with little success; she is badly injured. Hin, badly injured, shows up and lifts the big rock off Luke's leg. Luke then fights Darth Vader, engaging Vader on a level which even surprises the Dark Lord. Here Vader conjures a ball of Force energy (possibly his own interpretation of Force lightning), which Luke manages to deflect. They continue to battle and Luke, his actions guided by the spirit of Obi-Wan and his power augmented by the Kaiburr crystal, strikes Vader's sword arm, severing it. Undaunted, Vader picks up his lightsaber with his remaining arm, and again pursues the exhausted Luke. Vader, also exhausted, is about to win, staggering as he approaches to make the killing blow, and he falls into a pit; Luke senses that this does not kill Vader. As the story ends, a healed Leia and Luke drive off with their droids and with Halla into the mists of Mimban, ready to take on further off-world adventures.

Comment: Nice.  I remember seeing that book (from the cover in the your link) in bookstores.  Alan Dean Foster must have been busy doing movie work at the time - I read his Alien novelization when it came out.

Comment: Odd though - I am sure I saw the comics before 95, by that time I was living in Europe and was not reading comics much anymore.  Plus, wouldn't they have edited out the Luke-Leia romance?  Might it have been a re-issue, rather than the first?

Comment: Actually, the comic version only *added* things (characters) to the story. The romance subplot was left in. I've seen chatter (unsourced) that Lucas said it was allowed in the story to play the angle of the twins feeling a connection that they couldn't quite explain.